# Clipping shapefile with DEM using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile, dem

I have a layer with shapefiles that represent watersheds. I'd like to exclude watershed polygons (or sections of these polygons) that fall below 2500 meters.

Is there a way to do this by clipping portions of the shapefile with a digital elevation model?

This would be for ArcMap 10.7.1.

Comment: Please specify a software. In general terms, the solution will be to classify the DEM into two categories: 1 = elevation at or above 2500m, 0 = elevation below 2500m. Polygonize the classified DEM and use the polygon to clip the watershed layer.